# CakePHP Undefined Notice

Tags: cakephp

$this->request->data['User']['upgraded'] may or may not be set (it's a checkbox from the form). If it's not set, everything is working great, but I am getting an "Undefined index" notice in my debug.log

```
$this->User->update($user_id, $payment_id, $this->request->data['User']['upgraded']);
```

The following code fixes it, but is there a way to handle it without having to add the additional IF statement:

```
$upgraded = false;
if(isset($this->request->data['User']['upgraded'])) {
     $upgraded = $this->request->data['User']['upgraded'];
}
$this->User->update($member_id, $payment_id, $upgraded);
```

And, in my update() function, I check to see if $upgraded is null or not, but am still getting the error.

Comment: no, not really. unless you're on PHP7, in which case you could use the `??` null-coalescing operator, but that's still a "check".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hash class to eradicate the errors for potentially unset variables
Something like:

```
$this->User->update(
    $user_id, 
    $payment_id, 
    Hash::get(
       $this->request->data, 
      'User.upgraded', 
       false
);
```

where `false` is the default value for an unset field

[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::get)